# How to use an attribute in a directive to select data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a directive-element which uses the value of an attribute to make a http request and prints the response. The part of using the value of the attribute to make an http request is covered by using the $attrs in a controller which is associated with the directive. However, if I'm trying to output the data  with 3 different attribute values in the same document, all the directives output the same data.

I have made a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sGqq1P2t6Pxk65oqiAJg?p=preview) of my code to demonstrate my problem

**Basically what I want to do is this:**

```
<person personNumber='person1'></person>
<person personNumber='person2'></person>
<person personNumber='person3'></person>
```

My data from example.com/{person-number}:

*person 1:*

```
 {
   name: "John",
   city: "New York"
 }
```

*person 2:*

```
 {
      name: "Bob",
      city: "Los Angeles"
 }
```

*person 3:*

```
 {
      name: "Jay",
      city: "San Diego"
 }
```

**Wanted output:**

```
John: New York

Bob: Los Angeles

Jay: San Diego
```

**What I get:**

```
Jay: San Diego

Jay: San Diego

Jay: San Diego
```

What you see is that all the values have changed to the last http request. I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my angular code (also visible in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sGqq1P2t6Pxk65oqiAJg?p=preview)):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
    //mock json response
    var people = {
      person1: {
        name: "John",
        city: "New York"
      },
      person2: {
        name: "Bob",
        city: "Los Angeles"
      },
      person3: {
        name: "Jay",
        city: "San Diego"
      }
    };

    //mock $http.get to an api with url (www.example.com/{person})
    var self = this;
    function mockHttpGetService() {
      self.info = people[$attrs.personNumber];
    }
    mockHttpGetService();
  }
]);

app.directive('person', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: 'personController',
      controllerAs: 'person'
    };
  }
);
```

and my template:

```
<p>{{person.info.name}}: {{person.info.city}} </p>
```

**Question**

I think it might have something to do with the "scope" property of the directive, however I have tried all different versions ('=', '@', '<', '&'), but I am not able to get it to work.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that it has to do with the scope property in the directive.  You need this to make it work:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: 'personController',
  controllerAs: 'person',
  scope: {
    personNumber:'='
  }
};
```

updated plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/i4anaSJsSq8iKGgHo7eK?p=preview

The reason this was failing was before adding your scope property to the directive descriptor, its scope was that of the surrounding template where the directive was declared.  So since it's sharing scope among all instances of the directive, the last one assigned is assigned for all of them.  In this case `person3` got assigned last to `person-number` therefore all 3 instances are looking at the original scope's `person-number` value.

Isolate scope is what happens when you assign an object to the scope.  In this case I've assigned a new scope with the `personNumber`.  This is a unique scope per instance of the directive.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!